# Program is still in infinite recursion

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I am trying to create a Merge Sort using Wolfram Mathematica, but I am still getting this recursion error and I have no idea, where I made a misstake. I rewrite this code from Java, where it works just fine, so I guess it is some special thing for Wolfram. Do you have any idea, what could be wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot!

Heer is my code:

```
mergeSort[x_, left_, right_] := 
 Module[{array = x, middle, n1, n2, L, R, i, j, k}, 
  If[left < right,
    middle = (left + right) / 2;
    
    mergeSort[array, left, middle];
    mergeSort[array, middle + 1, right];
    
    n1 = middle - left + 1;
    n2 = right - middle;
    
    L = {};
    R = {};
    
    For[i = 1, i < n1, ++i,
     L[[i]] = array[[left + 1]];
     ];
    For[j = 1, j < n2, ++j,
     R[[j]] = array[[middle + 1 + j]];
     ];
    
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = left;
    
    While[i < n1 && j < n2,
     If[L[[i]] <= R[[j]],
      array[[k]] = L[[i]];
      i++;
      ,
      array[[k]] = R[[j]];
      j++;
      ];
     k++;
     ];
    
    While[i < n1, 
     array[[k]] = L[[i]];
     i++;
     k++;
     ];
    
    While[j < n2,
     array[[k]] = R[[j]];
     j++;
     k++;
     ];
    Return[array];
    ];
  ]
```

Here is my function call - `mergeSort[{58, 3, 98}, 0, 3];`

Answer (score 0):

You have three main problems in your code.

1. The GfG code you are trying to adapt is passing the array `arr` by reference, so each recursion is operating on the same object.  This doesn't ordinarily happen in Mathematica.  I have added `HoldFirst` to pass `array` [by reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32639/363).  An alternative would be to simply leave `array` out of the function calls altogether and modify it directly as a global variable. E.g.

   ```
   mergeSort[left_, right_] := Module[{},
     If[left < right,
      middle = Floor[(left + right)/2];
      mergeSort[left, middle];
      mergeSort[middle + 1, right];
      ...
   ```
2. Where the GfG code does `int m = (l + r) / 2` the result is rounded down.  This needs to be done explicitly in Mathematica: `middle = Floor[(left + right)/2]`.  Otherwise you get infinite recursion.
3. The GfG code uses zero-based arrays.  Mathematica uses one-based lists, so code such as `for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)` can be changed to `For[i = 1, i <= n1, ++i, ...`

You also had a typo from this line in the GfG code: `L[i] = arr[l + i]`, and finally you do not need to use [`Return`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171040/363) in Mathematica to return values at the end of a function.

```
Attributes[mergeSort] = HoldFirst;

mergeSort[array_Symbol, left_Integer, right_Integer] :=
 Module[{middle, n1, n2, L, R, i, j, k},
  If[left < right,
   middle = Floor[(left + right)/2];

   mergeSort[array, left, middle];
   mergeSort[array, middle + 1, right];

   n1 = middle - left + 1;
   n2 = right - middle;

   L = ConstantArray[Null, n1];
   R = ConstantArray[Null, n2];

   For[i = 1, i <= n1, ++i,
    L[[i]] = array[[left + i - 1]];
    ];
   For[j = 1, j <= n2, ++j,
    R[[j]] = array[[middle + j]];
    ];

   i = 1;
   j = 1;
   k = left;

   While[i <= n1 && j <= n2,
    If[L[[i]] <= R[[j]],
     array[[k]] = L[[i]];
     i++;
     ,
     array[[k]] = R[[j]];
     j++;
     ];
    k++;
    ];

   While[i <= n1,
    array[[k]] = L[[i]];
    i++;
    k++;
    ];

   While[j <= n2,
    array[[k]] = R[[j]];
    j++;
    k++;
    ];
   array
   ]
  ]

array = {58, 3, 98};

mergeSort[array, 1, Length[array]]
```

> {3, 58, 98}

Note this has changed the contents of `array`.

```
array
```

> {3, 58, 98}

***Alternative Version***

A version much more in the Mathematica idiom is this, by [Wellin, Gaylord & Kamin](https://books.google.gg/books?id=OuzV1M7b0WIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA198#v=onepage&q&f=false).

```
merge[lis_List, {}] := lis
merge[{}, lis_List] := lis

merge[{a_, ra___}, {b_, rb___}] :=
 If[a <= b,
  Join[{a}, merge[{b}, {ra, rb}]],
  Join[{b}, merge[{a, ra}, {rb}]]]

MergeSort[{}] := {}
MergeSort[{x_}] := {x}
MergeSort[lis_List] := Module[{div = Floor[Length[lis]/2]},
  merge[MergeSort[Take[lis, div]], MergeSort[Drop[lis, div]]]]

MergeSort[{58, 3, 98}]
```

> {3, 58, 98}

Comment: Hm.. I am not really sure how to fix this anyway, because in other languages like Java, it just works.

Comment: @I don't see how it could work.  Maybe you should post the Java code too.

Comment: Here is code from GfG - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/